# Installing 'Windows 8 Consumer Preview' on virtual Box

Tags: virtualization, windows-8-preview

I started my morning with installig windows 8 consumer review on my Virtual Box. I spent 2hrs and still unble to find the solution (How to install it on virtual box I am following [this tutorial](http://techpp.com/2011/09/14/guide-to-install-windows-8-on-virtualbox/)

Error from Virtual Box:
Enable VT-x support!

I googled and found some modification requires in "system->Acceleration" tab setting in virtual box. But "Acceleration" tab is disabled at my end.

I am using x86 platform (I know these system never designed by considering fact of virtualization :( )
need your suggestion to resolve this problem!

Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: What CPU does your system have?

Comment: I assume you are installing it on a virtual box so that you don't need to overwrite your main OS to avoid a re-install?  If this is the case then I think your better simply creating a new partition on your drive and installing there, then when your finished playing (won't be long because it still isn't perfect) you can delete the partition.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks. I like your idea! I will give try for that.

Answer (score 1):

Not all x86 CPUs are created equal when it comes to virtualization. VT-x is an Intel feature that wasn't included in all CPU models.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29 and http://ark.intel.com/

Comment: thanks a lot for your exact information. I used Virtual Box user guide. you can see here [link](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html)  (search for "Unfortunately, the x86 platform was never designed to be virtualized")  I think, I assumed thing w/o enough searching... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same thing, but followed this blogs instructions.  There are some modifications you need to do to the Virtual Box.  I would try the steps described here.

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/virtually-windows-8-how-to-set-up-the-consumer-preview-in-virtualbox/70330

Comment: @EI: thanks for the link. I will get back on this.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same settings as for the previous Win8 version, and it worked. I will list all the settings in the tabs:

(I am translating names from my native language to english, sorry)

System:

1. Tab mainboard: memory set to 2048 MB (I use 32bit, for 64 use double that), IO APIC is enabled, other checkboxes are unchecked
2. CPU, 2 cpus, execution cap is set to 100%
3. Acceleration, botch checkboxes set

Screen:

1. Video: 16 MB, 3D acceleration enabled, 2d acceleration is off
2. Remote desktop enabled, this is how I use Win8, VB window sux

Hard Drive:

1. I use dynamically allocated storage, 43 GB

Sounds:

1. Defaults

Network:

1. Bridged card

All the rest is default.

As far as I remember your CPU must support hardware virtualization to make it work.

Comment: Dear Tom, Thanks for your detailed steps. But at my case, System step(3) Acceleration tab is disabled.